# Determine if an `xcolor` color has been defined

Tags: color, conditionals

Is there a way to determine if a color has been defined by `xcolor`? I am trying to add compatibility to a library using multiple versions of `tcolorbox` where certain colors were recently renamed; I'd like to redefine them if they are undefined.

Comment: Use `\providecolor` it defines a color only if it dosen't exist already

Comment: there is `\@ifundefinedcolor` to test a color.